# Using %PUT to correctly format the dynamic file name

Tags: sas

I have a SAS script that reads in a CSV file and stores it in a SAS data set:

```
LIBNAME IN '\\path\Data';
FILENAME CSV '\\path\Data\DT.csv';

DATA IN.DT;
  INFILE CSV DLM=',' DSD FIRSTOBS=1;
  INPUT KEY VALUE1 VALUE2;
RUN;
```

I want to change it such that instead of expecting the input to be named `DT.csv`, it would accept an input named `DT-2016-03-03-TEST.csv`, or whatever the current date is. In other words, I need to use a dynamic value in my `FILENAME` statement.

Here is what I have so far:

```
%LET curday   = %SYSFUNC(day("&sysdate"d));
%LET curmonth = %SYSFUNC(month("&sysdate"d));
%LET curyear  = %SYSFUNC(year("&sysdate"d));

%PUT %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&curday, z2.));

FILENAME CSV "\\path\Data\DT-&curyear-&curmonth-&curday-TEST.csv";
```

But the string it generates is like `Data\DT-2016-3-3-TEST.csv` rather than `Data\DT-2016-03-03-TEST.csv`

In other words, the trailing zeros are not there. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use either a macro variable or a big group of macro functions (whichever you'd like). We'll go with creating macro variables for readability purposes. Based upon what you've said, we know a few things about the pattern:

1. It starts with `DT-`
2. It has today's date in a `yyyy-mm-dd` format
3. It ends in `.csv`

Two of these are static values, and one needs to be dynamic in a specific format. Let's get crackin'.

Start off by storing the path in its own macro variable. This makes the code more generalizable to other applications (i.e. you can copy/paste old code for new programs! It's good to be lazy in the programming world).

`%let path = \\path\data;`

Next, let's build our dynamic pattern using a `%let` statement. We know it starts with `DT-`:

**___________________________________________**

`%let file = DT-`

**___________________________________________**

We can now cross #1 off the list! Let's knock out #2.

Two functions will help us get this in the order that we want:

1. `%sysfunc()`
2. `today()`

We'll encapsulate `today()` with `%sysfunc()`. `%sysfunc()` lets us run most non-macro-language SAS functions, and also has the added benefit of returning the value in a format that you desire using an additional argument. This is really helpful for us here.

So, let's grab today's date as a numeric SAS date, then convert it to `yymmddx10` format, where `x` is some delimiter keyword. We'll use `yymmddd10.` - that is, a format that specifies yyyy-mm-dd. The extra `d` means dash.

**___________________________________________**

`%let file = DT-%sysfunc(today(), yymmddd10.)`

**___________________________________________**

2 is now out of the way. Hard part's over! All we need to do is append `.csv` to it, and we'll be all set.

**___________________________________________**

`%let file = DT-%sysfunc(today(), yymmddd10.).csv;`

**___________________________________________**

You can confirm the macro variable `file`'s value with a `%put` statement:

`%put NOTE: This is my filename: &file;`

You should see in green text in the log `NOTE: This is my filename: DT-2016-03-03.csv`

Now, we'll just put it all together:

```
%let path = \\path\data;
%let file = DT-%sysfunc(today(), yymmddd10.).csv;

libname IN "&path";
filename CSV "&path\&file";

data in.DT;
    infile csv dlm=',' dsd firstobs=1;
    input key value1 value2;
run;
```

You've now got a dynamic way to read in these CSVs, *and* you can adapt this code elsewhere. Awesomesauce. I think you've earned yourself a celebratory coffee, and maybe a biscotti or two; don't go too crazy.

Comment: Fantastic!
Very Well explained.

Comment: Nice answer.  One minor note: you mean `filename CSV` right?

Comment: Also - it might be worth mentioning as an aside that OP could've put the `z2.` in the original code (though your way is clearly better).

Comment: Good catch, Joe. Yes, I meant to put `filename` :) I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Stu's answer is absolutely correct.  For the tl;dr version.

`%put` echos stuff to the log.  All you are doing is "putting" the result of `%SYSFUNC(PUTN(&curday, z2.))` to the log.  You are not updating the value in `&curday`.

Try

```
%LET curday = %SYSFUNC(PUTN(&curday, z2.));
```

Do that for the other `curmonth`, too.

Take the time and read Stu's answer.